# Export file asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, pydub

I am trying to save a song edited using `pydub` in an await expression (because it's a Discord bot) but it always blocks the gateway and stops the bot from sending anything.

I tried

```py
await song.export("audios/"+filename+".ogg", format="ogg")
```

but it gives me

```
TypeError: object _io.BufferedRandom can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: This is a bit complicated because it needs another thread to run the blocking function. A starting point is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import asyncio
def SongExport(Arg1,Arg2):#example
    song.export("audios/"+filename+".ogg", format="ogg")
    return 1#example
@bot.tree.command(name="exportSong")
def exportSong(interaction: discord.Interaction)
blocking_coro = asyncio.to_thread(SongExport, Arg1, Arg2)
result = await blocking_coro
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Perfect! Although through doing this made the other code blocking so I moved the entire function. And through doing that it takes a bit for discord to send but overall it works!